# How do you mock an argument being passed into wrapper.instance().method in jest/enzyme?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I'm struggling to test one of my event handler functions

This code here is a function within my parent class component, which updates these states.

The "inputValue" comes from the child component which gets passed to this function in the parent component

```
filterPosts = (inputValue) => {
    const myPost = this.state.posts.filter(post => post.userId === Number(inputValue));
    this.setState({ inputValue,  myPost })
};
```

I'm struggling to write a test for this. I understand that I need to use enzymes shallow renderer

```
wrapper.instance().filterPosts
```

But I have no idea how to test this. I want to try and put a mock argument as my "inputValue" in this test like this:

```
const mockInputValue = 1;
wrapper.instance().filterPosts(mockInputValue);
```

However this keeps returning undefined. If I just use:`wrapper.instance().filterPosts()`
,this still returns undefined

Is there any way to pass this mockInputValue into this instance method?

I'm still quite new to testing, any help will be appreciated

**EDIT**

This is how filterPosts is invoked and this.state.myPost is rendered: 
(only renders only if there array is present in this.state.myPosts from the filter in filterPosts())

```js
render() {
        return (
            <div className='app'>
                <Header title='Posts Page' inputValue={this.state.inputValue} filterPosts={this.filterPosts}/>
                    <div className='my-posts'>
                        <h2>My posts</h2>
                        {
                            this.state.myPost.map(post => {
                                return (
                                    <Post
                                        key={post.id}
                                        userId={post.userId}
                                        postId={post.id}
                                        postTitle={post.title}
                                        postBody={post.body}
                                    />
                                );
                            })
                        }
                    </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
```

In terms of my child component, the child passes the event change from the input box like this:

```js
<input
                className='input-filterPosts'
                value={props.inputValue}
                placeholder='Please select between 1 and 10'
                onChange={(inputValue) => props.filterPosts(inputValue.target.value)} 
                />
```

Comment: Woah, this question changed quite a bit with the edit.. anyhow: is it *supposed* to return something? Looks like it's setting state, not returning.

Comment: how do you render `this.state.myPost`? how this `filterPosts` is invoked?

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to stack overflow and I'm not use to structuring my questions.

Comment: I've updated the question with more info now!

Comment: @Stratadox its meant to set the state. Essentially, this.state.posts has an array of posts, and filterPosts will filter the array of posts by userId, then update this.state.myPost with the filtered array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the function's purpose is to set the `myPost` and `inputValue` attributes of the component's state given an input value. So you should test that the function sets these attributes correctly.

Your code should work. You can pass an argument to the function on your instance like you are doing.

Here's an article that discusses directly testing react component functions: https://bambielli.com/til/2018-03-04-directly-test-react-component-methods/

If you want to test that the function was called with your given input value argument, you can use a [Jest spy](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestspyonobject-methodname)

---

Here is a code snippet below testing your component's function. I hope it helps.

```
describe("filterPosts", () => {
  let wrapper;
  let instance;
  const mockInputValue = 1;

  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = shallow(<App />);
    instance = wrapper.instance();
    jest.spyOn(instance, "filterPosts");
    instance.filterPosts(mockInputValue);
  });

  it("calls the function with a given input value", () => {
    expect(instance.filterPosts).toHaveBeenCalledWith(1);
  });

  it("sets the inputValue state attribute to the given input value", () => {
    expect(wrapper.state("inputValue")).toEqual(1);
  });

  it("sets myPost to a filtered array of posts", () => {
    // whatever updated state you expect for "myPost"
    expect(wrapper.state("myPost")).toEqual([]);
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this solution is works. I didn't realise you could use jest.spyOn for instances which is why all my tests were failing. Really appreciate you taking the time to post an indepth solution as well! Thanks!

Comment: After a bit more testing, I also found why it didn't work. I was using wrapper.instance.filterPosts within the "it" test. For me, i keep getting undefined if i do that. Ever since I moved it to beforeEach, it finally works!

Comment: No problem :) I find using beforeEach is helpful for setting up data shared between tests. It helps keep the test cases clear and "to-the-point."